# Different height in parent DIV

Tags: html, css, syntax, scroll

http://jsfiddle.net/fdezluis96/JJ29E/3/

I'm making a Twitter-Like bar, and I want it to display some notifications as shown in the JSFiddle. It's a menu bar (Home, connect, friends, account) and a login button, and all is dynamic to the browser width, so I can't put it `margin:auto;`. I want to be shown as in the second example, but with the first's syntax, since I can't use tables. Code:

```
.navigation{
    padding:5px;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue, Tahoma, Verdana;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:20px;
    background: #333;
    height:24px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.subnavigation{
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-top-width:0px;
    border-bottom-width:0px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #666;
    border-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}
table{
    float:left;
}

​
```

And HTML:

```
<!--Example one, desired syntax, not working-->
<div class="navigation">A
    <div class="subnavigation">B.</div>
    A
</div>

<br />
<!--Example two, working but with tables, so its not viable-->
<table>
    <td class="navigation">A</td>
</table>
<table>
    <td class="navigation subnavigation">
        Scroll content<br />
        Lorem ipsum...LALALALA<br />
        Just more stuff<br />
        And more<br />
        And a bit more...
    </td>
</table>
<table>
    <td class="navigation">A</td>
</table>
```

​Thanks ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay. A few things are happening here.

First, you really need to delimit the items in your navigation. I've used divs, and I've given them all `float: left` via the class `item`. This accomplishes two things: It gets all your items on one line, and it wraps their containers around them, so your "dropdown" will have size appropriate for the largest item in the dropdown.

Second, you need to remove `overflow: hidden` from `.navigation`. This will allow elements (`.item` elements, in this case) to extend beyond the border of this element.

Third, adjust for margins and padding. I've kept the 5px padding on `.navigation`, but I've added a negative top margin and some side margins to `.item`.

I'm unclear as to whether you wanted these items to scroll, or be displayed as a dropdown, so I've done both:

[as a dropdown](http://jsfiddle.net/JJ29E/9/)

[as a scroll-box](http://jsfiddle.net/JJ29E/10/)

Comment: Yes, I mean the dropdown effect but I can't implement it on my web, http://live-pin.com/ live demo, help please.

Comment: WHY OH WHY do you have `margin-top: -200px` on `.notify`?

Comment: @Abhishek What, exactly, did I do again?

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish the same thing using `divs`, but for navigation a `ul` would be more semantic.

[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/1906104)

```
li {list-style-type:none; display:block; float:left;}
.navigation{ height:25px; background: #333;}
.subnavigation{width:25%; height:100px; background:gray;}


<ul class="navigation">
        <li>A</li>
    <li class="subnavigation"></li>
    <li>A</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hmmm, that would work, but not man, dont know what to do and why it doesnt work, http://live-pin.com/ heres the live example, thanks!

Comment: There is used in the full menu, you would need to see it complete to understand, doesn't work like in your example.

Comment: I'm asking you to do some work and to boil it down the absolute minimum amount of code where it stops working. Posting your site is overwhelming. Put in some time and find the exact point where the concepts in my demo fall apart on your site.

Comment: I have no idea of what happens, but when I put it on my code just doesn't work, maybe CSS stuff, http://jsfiddle.net/fdezluis96/P3HxB/ heres the navbar.

Answer (score -1):

If you put:

```
display: inline;
```

in `subnavigation` class, you should get it to look similar to your table example.

Working example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/JJ29E/4/

The result is this:

[image]